# C++ Winapi Listbox string with space ends up in new line

Tags: c++, string, winapi, listbox, visual-studio-2017

Quick question, if I create a ListBox and add a string with a space in it to the listbox, the listbox ends up pretty messy because everything after the space will be added into the next line. In this case shown below it's even worse, because the full amount of numbers is not added to the listbox due to this problem. Is it a problem caused by the converting process of a string to a char? How can i prevent it from happening?

Here is the code i use for the Listbox and the adding Process:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{


    LBTest = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
        , L"LISTBOX",NULL
        , WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL| LBS_NOTIFY
        , 7, 7, 300, 600
        , hWnd, (HMENU)19, hInst, NULL);
    std::wstring str,str2=L"Item Number ";
    std::wstringstream ss;
    for (int l = 0; l < 210; l++)
    {
        ss <<str2<< std::to_wstring(l);
        ss >> str;
        int pos = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
        SendMessage(LBTest, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM)l);

    }

    break;
}
```

Here is the full code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Testproject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>


#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
const UINT WM_WINDOW_UPDATE = WM_APP + 0;

HINSTANCE hInst;                               
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            
HWND Button1,LBTest;



ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK ListBoxExampleProc(HWND, UINT,
WPARAM, LPARAM);




int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);




LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTPROJECT, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
MyRegisterClass(hInstance);


if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
{
    return FALSE;
}

HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance,   MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTPROJECT));

MSG msg;


while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TESTPROJECT));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TESTPROJECT);
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}


BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
hInst = hInstance; //

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

if (!hWnd)
{
  return FALSE;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{


    LBTest = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
        , L"LISTBOX",NULL
        , WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL| LBS_NOTIFY
        , 7, 7, 300, 600
        , hWnd, (HMENU)19, hInst, NULL);
    std::wstring str,str2=L"Item Number ";
    std::wstringstream ss;
    for (int l = 0; l < 210; l++)
    {
        ss.clear()
        ss <<str2<< std::to_wstring(l);
        ss >> str;
        int pos = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
        SendMessage(LBTest, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM)l);

    }

    break;
}
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);

        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        //TODO: Zeichencode, der hdc verwendet, hier einfügen...



        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}


INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Listbox result:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the current behavior?

Comment: list box 100% not have this behavior and this at all not related to listbox. this is some your error with string data

Comment: ye i added a screen of current behavior in the post. I'm sure it has to do with the stringstream but I can't imagine why this happens.

Comment: try DbgPrint strings which you add to listbox

Comment: To preclude whether this is an issue with old control implementations, can you [enable visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx)?

Comment: Your DbgPrint gave me an Idea.It works with str = str2 + std::to_wstring(l); .I'm used to stringstream so i did not think about that. I'm still not sure what happens but stringstream does make strange things with it.

Comment: Um, because the `>>` operator extracts words not lines.

Comment: oh my god, i'm such a dumbass. I have to use str=ss.str(). How the hell did that happen?!

Comment: It's not entirely obvious, why you are using a string stream at all. It doesn't buy you anything over simple string concatenation. You aren't passing any non-string objects into the string stream, where this would be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you do some debugging? You simply have to learn how to debug.

Comment: the reason l used it was to directly input l into the string. The std::to_wstring was just a result of trying to fix the buggy part. but in this case you're right. this is not the original program it is used, i only made this program to find the error because it focuses on the problem.